# Session variable shows value on echo but doesn't show when checked with isset

Tags: php, session, isset

I've a login page, where I'm setting the admin ID as a session variable

```
$_SESSION['adminUserId'] = $row['id'];
```

Now I've a header.php file which is called first on every page. To display the header.
And the first line of Header.php has

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['adminUserId'])) {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

Now the strange part about this is, while I'm doing echo $_SESSION['adminUserId']), it displays the value of the variable. But when I'm checking the variable with isset, the result is false. I'm unable to understand this, as how this is happening. 
Also, another strange thing, include header.php is the first line of code for every page, it works fine for all the pages apart from one, where it redirects the user to index.php

I've tried changing the variable name, setting the variable in a different way. But doesn't work for the specific page.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['adminUserId'])) {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

The expected result for a logged in user should be true but for a not logged in user it should be false, but it is showing vice versa

index.php (Here the session is getting set)

```
$qry = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."' AND role ='".$role."' AND country ='".$country."'");
  $qry->execute();
  $admin = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  // print_r($admin);
  if($admin){
    foreach($admin as $row)
      {
    if($username==$row['username'] && $password==$row['password'] && $role == 'Admin')
    {
      $country = $row['country'];
      $_SESSION['Country'] = $country;
      $DEO_id = $row['id'];
      $_SESSION['adminUserId'] = $DEO_id;
      $session_role = $row['role'];
      $_SESSION['session_role'] = $session_role;
      $usernameAdmin = $row['username'];
      $_SESSION['city'] = $usernameAdmin;
      $_SESSION['isAdminLoggedIn'] = "True";
      header('location:admin/dashboard.php');
    }
    elseif($username==$row['username'] && $password==$row['password'] && $role == 'Data Entry User')
    {
      $DEO_id = $row['id'];
      $_SESSION['dataEntry_ID'] = $DEO_id;
      $country = $row['country'];
      $_SESSION['Country'] = $country;
      $session_role = $row['role'];
      $_SESSION['session_role'] = $session_role;

      header('location:data_operator/dashboard.php'); 
    }
    else
    {
      $error = "Invalid Username or Password.";
    }
    }
  }
  {
    $error = "Invalid Username or Password.";
  }
```

dashboard.php (Where the header.php is called and code works fine)

```
<?php include('header.php');
include('../include/dbcon.php');

?>
```

Now there's another link in the dashboard page

```
<a href="new-registration.php" class="btn btn-success btn-icon-split" style="width:100%">
<span class="text">New Registration</span>
</a>
```

When I see the new-registration.php page, this is how it looks like

```
<?php include('header.php'); 
include('../include/dbcon.php');
?>
```

And now the final header.php(where all this action is taking place)

```
<?php 
include('../include/dbcon.php');
 if(!isset($_SESSION['adminUserId']))
  {
  header("Location: ../index.php");
  }

?>
```

Comment: Are the `echo` and `isset` happening on the same page? Are you using `session_start()` on top of this page?

Comment: @deceze yes both happening on the same page, and I've used session_start(). It works perfectly fine for other pages, but is not working for one specific page.

Comment: Then we don't have enough context here to tell you why it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you are including the header.php file correctly on the page you are having problems?

Comment: What more do you need, @deceze, I can show you the code files.

Comment: @WKoppel as I said, working fine for other pages, but not for one specific page.

Comment: Well, we need enough to *reproduce* the problem. We see that you assign something to the session, and that you're checking it. That should work fine as is.

Comment: @deceze exactly, this should work fine as is, but is not. That's the reason I put it here.

Comment: So *something else* must be going on here we're not seeing…

Comment: @SanjayNainani He is saying that you don't give us enough.

Comment: Is there a possibility that you might overwrite this variable somewhere?

Comment: @deceze, I've edited the question to give you more insight of the code.

Comment: Not seeing `session_start` anywhere. You also seem to have a circular or redundant import between `header.php` and `dbcon.php`.

Comment: @WKoppel 

if you see the dasboard.php page is the first one to be called after login, and it includes header.php. And it works fine here. But when I click on new-registration.php link, there it breaks. Although the logic is the same for both.

Comment: @deceze, session_start is there in the file, I've just given the relevant part of the code. And thanks for pointing out the redundant code.